# Go: Missing port in address

Tags: http, go, tcp

I was trying to make a simple webapp in Go/Golang. My main fuction code is :

```
func main() {
fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
http.Handle("/", fileServer)
http.HandleFunc("/form", formHandler)
http.HandleFunc("/hello", helloHandler)

fmt.Printf("Starting server at port 8080\n")
if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

}

When I run the `go run main.go` I get the following error:

```
listen tcp: address ;8080: missing port in address
exit status 1
```

I tried using the `lsof -i :8080` command but got no output. Chaging the port to `:80` from `:8080` had no effect. `nc -l :8080` didn't work too.

How do I resolve this issue?

PS: I'm using Fedora OS

Comment: `tcp: address ;8080:` there is a semicolon before 8080, was this same in original code?

Comment: @s3vt Yes, there was a typo in the first compilation. Then I fixed it with `:80`. Ran the `go build` & `go run main.go` commands again but to no avail

Comment: was the error same with ":80" too or different. see if there is anything else running with port 8080, `netstat -tlnp | grep 8080` , if nothing shows up; Run  again with `go run main.go`. With port configured as 8080 in code

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but incase of anyone else who may have this issue. Try specifying the port as "localhost:8080" instead of just ":8080"

In this case, the code should be like this:

```
func main() {
     fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
     http.Handle("/", fileServer)
     http.HandleFunc("/form", formHandler)
     http.HandleFunc("/hello", helloHandler)

     fmt.Printf("Starting server at port 8080\n")
     if err := http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
func main() {
    fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))

    httpf := http.NewServeMux()
    httpf.Handle("/", fileServer)
    httpf.HandleFunc("/form", settings.Grp_Insert)
    httpf.HandleFunc("/hello", settings.Grp_Insert)

    srv := &http.Server{
        ReadTimeout:       3 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:      6 * time.Second,
        Addr:              "localhost:8080",
        IdleTimeout:       15 * time.Second,
        ReadHeaderTimeout: 3 * time.Second,
        Handler:           httpf,
    }

    fmt.Printf("Starting server at port 8080\n")
    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Code Changes]

Change it to localhost:3000, it will work. worked for me

```
if err := http.ListenAndServe("localhost:3000", nil); err != nil {
```